# Centrar texto dentro de un div

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla Juego con los siguientes valores:

```
Schema::create('juegos', function (Blueprint $table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('numero')->unique();
        $table->string('nombre');
        $table->unsignedInteger('agrupacion_id');
        $table->foreign('agrupacion_id')->references('id')->on('agrupacions');
        $table->text('materiales');
        $table->text('organizacion');
        $table->text('desarrollo');
        $table->string('foto');
        $table->text('observaciones');
        $table->text('variantes');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Y se muestran los datos de un juego en la siguiente vista:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute"><u>Datos del juego</u></h1>

    <div class="pl-5 pr-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 card card-1">
            <h2 class="text-center card-title">Nº {{$j->numero}}: {{$j->nombre}}</h2>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url($j->ruta())}}"/>
            <div class="card-body">
                <center>
                    <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Materiales necesarios: {{$j->materiales}}</span>
                    <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Organcización de equipos: {{$j->agrupacion->nombre}}</span>
                </center>

                <hr>

                <h3>Posicionamiento:</h3>
                <span class="badge badge-cat badge-primary">{{$j->organizacion}}</span>

                <hr>

                <h3>¿En que consiste?</h3>
                <span class="badge badge-cat badge-primary">{{$j->desarrollo}}</span>

                <hr>

                <h3>Normas:</h3>
                <span class="badge badge-cat badge-primary">{{$j->observaciones}}</span>

                <hr>

                <h3>Variaciones:</h3>
                <span class="badge badge-cat badge-primary">{{$j->variantes}}</span>

                <hr>

                <?php
                    $contenidos=$j->enlaces;
                ?>

                @if(count($contenidos))
                    <h3>Habilidades que seran puesta a prueba de los participantes:</h3>
                    @foreach($contenidos as $contenido)
                        <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">{{$contenido->contenido->nombre}}</span>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Y al crear un juego, me veo con esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que el contenido de los textos no se salgan del div. ¿Como lo logro?

Edito: He dejado solamente badge-primary, y me encuentro esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al fin hay saltos de línea, pero desearia más espacio entre el fondo azulado y el texto, pues arriba y abajo hay un buen espacio, pero de izquierda a derecha esta no existe ese espaciamiento.

Tambien he probado class="alert alert-info":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se ve nada bien.

Otra cosa que he probado es class="btn-primary", dandome el mismo resultado que badge-primary.
Tambien he probado class="alert-primary", el cual da el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ve mejor, pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema que con btn-primary y badge-primary, que el fondo azulado no da espacio entre la letra y el fondo blanco.

Comment: jeje el problema es que no sabes usar bien bootstrap, tal como lo has puesto las clases nunca te iran bien.

Answer (score 1):

el problema se debe a que estas usando la clase `.badge` de bootstrap y esta por defecto contiene la propiedad `white-space: nowrap;` que hace que el texto se vea asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo mejor es que cambies toda esa clase por otro distinta por ejemplo `class="alert alert-info"`

Comment: He probado a dejar solo badge-primary. Eso me ha solucionado el problema, pero me ha causado otro, por lo que he actualizado mi problema.

Comment: Pero si te lo he dicho, no puedes usar la clase .badge ni sus variantes

Comment: <span class="badge badge-cat badge-primary">{{$j->organizacion}}</span>

Comment: Tiene que estar asi

Comment: <span class="alert alert-info">{{$j->organizacion}}</span>

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas la documentación de bootstrap

Comment: Si utilizo class="alert alert-info" ni se ve.

Comment: Agrega esto....

Comment: <span class="alert alert-info" style="float:left">{{$j->organizacion}}</span>

Comment: Pues al final hice esto: class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px;"

Comment: Así he logrado que se vea, pero ahora me fijo que no funciona las etiquetas <hr>.

Answer (score 1):

¿Ya probaste con párrafos?

```
<h3>Posicionamiento:</h3>
<p>{{$j->organizacion}}</p>
```

Comment: Es una opción, el problema es que obligatoriamente tendria que dejarlo con el tradicional de letras negras y fondo blanco, y quisiera que conservara ese fondo azulado.

Comment: <p style="background-color:#0f7bff; color:#fff">{{$j->organizacion}}</p>

Answer (score -1):

Voy a explicar lo que he hecho al final.

Esta es la nueva vista:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1 class="text-center text-mute"><u>Datos del juego</u></h1>

    <div class="pl-5 pr-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-3 card card-1">
            <h2 class="text-center card-title">Nº {{$j->numero}}: {{$j->nombre}}</h2>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{url($j->ruta())}}"/>
            <div class="card-body">

                <hr>
                <center>
                    <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Materiales necesarios: {{$j->materiales}}</span>
                    <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">Agrupación de los jugadores: {{$j->agrupacion->nombre}}</span>
                </center>
                <hr>

                <h3>Organización:</h3>
                <p class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$j->organizacion}}</p>

                <h3>Desarrollo del juego</h3>
                <p class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$j->desarrollo}}</p>

                <h3>Reglas y observaciones:</h3>
                <p class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$j->observaciones}}</p>

                @if(!empty($j->variantes))
                    <h3>Variantes:</h3>
                    <p class="badge-primary" style="float: left; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 4px; border-radius: 5px;">{{$j->variantes}}</p>
                @endif

                <?php
                    $contenidos=$j->enlaces;
                ?>

                @if(count($contenidos))
                    <h3>Habilidades que seran puesta a prueba de los participantes:</h3>
                    <center>
                        @foreach($contenidos as $contenido)
                            <span class="badge badge-cat badge-info">{{$contenido->contenido->nombre}}</span>
                        @endforeach
                    </center>
                @endif

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Y da este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]